# prelink-rtld: segfault at 318

Tags: 14.04, server, kernel, segmentation-fault

I'm noticing the following error in my server (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS). Could you please advise on this?

```
Oct 22 01:29:27 xxxxxxxxx kernel: [1452400.314336] prelink-rtld[57301]: segfault at 318 ip 000000000040ac1e sp 00007ffc3c7639a0 error 4 in prelink-rtld[400000+11000]
Oct 22 01:29:35 xxxxxxxxx kernel: [1452409.016933] prelink-rtld[62382]: segfault at 318 ip 000000000040ac1e sp 00007ffe731147c0 error 4 in prelink-rtld[400000+11000]
Oct 22 01:29:40 xxxxxxxxx kernel: [1452413.651953] prelink-rtld[62746]: segfault at 318 ip 000000000040ac1e sp 00007fff0a220c00 error 4 in prelink-rtld[400000+11000]
```